# TypeError: errors.each is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to pass data from the view to an appended template like this;

```
error: function(user, response){
  //create flash message with errors and render new page
  var failureErrors = $.parseJSON(response.responseText).errors;
  var errorView = new Skymama.Views.ErrorMessages();                        
  $("#error_messages").append(errorView.render({errors: failureErrors}).el);                                
}
```

and the flash error view is ;

```
Skymama.Views.ErrorMessages = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: JST['flash/error_messages'],

    render: function(templateData) {            
    this.$el.html( this.template(templateData) );
    return this;
  },
```

while the flash error template is;

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
        <i class="icon-remove"></i>
    </button>
    <div id="error_list">
        <ul>
            <%  errors.each(function(error){ %>
                <li>hello</li>
            <% }); %>  
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
});
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native JavaScript objects don't have a `each` property.

```
<%  _(errors).each(function(error){ %>
```